# Should I avoid changing the CFBundleName of my iOS app for a new release?

Tags: ios, updates

I have an already released iOS app with a certain `CFBundleName` in its Info.plist.

For an update, I changed the `CFBundleName` (and hence, the name of the generated .app product) for consistency reasons. This is invisible to the user, who only sees the `CFBundleDisplayName`.

However, it seems that the updates on clients’ devices don't work correctly — the update progress bar reaches the end, jumps back to the beginning, and stops. The only solution is to delete and reinstall the app.

So:

- Is is forbidden to change the `CFBundleName` of an already existing app?
- Is it the thing that breaks my updates?
- If so, why is this not checked by the validation process by Apple?

Comment: CFBundle name is by default product name and usually you change ${PRODUCT_NAME} in project build settings. I dont think it should be a problem with app update. I remember I changed it for one of our app which was developed by someone else and we updated it with our new code (and hence new ${PRODUCT_NAME} & Bundle name)

Comment: But a side effect is that it does change the name of your app in the filesystem. Isn't that a problem for updates then?

Comment: yes the name has been changed but it caused no harm to our app. It got updated without an issue.

Comment: So you're positive it wasn't just the display name, but the real name of the app?

Comment: What I am saying is that it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two years, I am answering this old question with a best-guess answer: no, one should not especially avoid changing the the CFBundleName.