# Consequences of Changing CFBundleName? iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, watchkit, cfbundledisplayname

The wrong app name is displayed in the Apple Watch app in the My Watch list. It shows the CFBundleName contents. Advice has been [given in the Apple Developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1122040) to set the CFBundleName and the CFBundleDisplayName in all 3 apps (iPhone App, Watch App, Watch Extension). Changing the CFBundleDisplayName is not enough.

So, I am considering changing the CFBundleName. **Our team has an existing app**. I need to know what will happen if I do change the CFBundleName. The [Apple doc Core Foundation Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) says it's "The short display name of the bundle".

Items of concern are:

- Existing App Updates Succeeding
- Accessing old content via NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults
- Accessing old content via NSKeyedArchiver (un)archiveRootObject to/from NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) related location.

The SO post [Should I avoid changing the CFBundleName of my iOS app for a new release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405281/should-i-avoid-changing-the-cfbundlename-of-my-ios-app-for-a-new-release) is what got me concerned about app updates.

We store stuff that the user has paid for into the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,.. related location.

It's important to get this right and treat our existing users well. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you push your update? How did it go? On my dev device, changing the CFBundleName made all data disappear, as if it were looking for it in a different folder. I changed CFBundleName back and there it was again.

Comment: We have not yet pushed. I didn't see that behavior on our test devices. Everything worked as normal.

Comment: Thanks. Got it figured out, that was b/c of the way MagicalRecord names the store.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Nycen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Items of concern are...

None of those are affected. Change away! The app is uniquely identified by its bundle id. Defaults and archiving do not consult the name in any way. The names are just user-facing strings and that is *all* they are.